# @masterthesis doesn't work for bibtex citation

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, thesis

I'm using bibtex and I would like to know how to cite a **@masterthesis**. I've exported Mendeley's citations and it has only the @phdthesis style, which actually works. Is there any way to make work with **@masterthesis** instead? My bibliography at the end of the paper gets wrong.

I'm using **abntcite.sty**.

Here goes the code:

```
@masterthesis{Filho2016Automatic,
    author = {Silva{ }Filho, P. F. F.},
    institution = {Dissertação (Mestrado) - ITA},
    pages = 159,
    school = {Dissertação (Mestrado) - ITA},
    title = {Automatic Landmark Recognition in aerial images for the autonomous navigation system of Unmanned Aerial Vehicles},
    year = 2016
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcoe to TeX SX! `biblatex` knows the `masterthesis` entry type.

Comment: Which bibliography style are you using? Can you add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: Typo: It should be `@mastersthesis`

Comment: Mendeley is wrong: it should be `@mastersthesis`

Answer (score 7):

Actually, I found out that @master**s**thesis works, with the "s", instead of @masterthesis.

Comment: **You** found out. Or you read the comments posted 90 minutes before you answered your question?

Comment: I actually found out without reading the comments =)

Comment: Yes @mastersthesis works